# Trying to find function that defines a parabolic surface

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Say we are working in three dimensions and we have a function $u_1(x, y) = x^2$. Ie. this is just the regular $x^2$ parabola except it's now defined all along the way $y$-axis and forms a surface.

Say we also have a function $u_2(x, y) = y^2$. Ie. this is just the regular $y^2$ parabola except it's now defined all along the way $x$-axis and forms a surface.

...now where I'm going with this is that I would like to be able to define $u_3(x,y)$ such that it is the 'same kind of parabola' except instead being on the $y$-axis or the $x$-axis it is now defined on the vector $(1,1)$...Ie. one of the above surface 'rotated' 45 degrees about the $z$ axis. What would be the equation for $u(x,y)$ in this case?

Comment: It is $z=(y-x)^2$.

Comment: How did you arrive at that equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a transformation

$$u=x-y\\
v=x+y$$

Your new $u$-axis is the original $y+x=0$ line. This is the line you want to construct your parabola upon. So the parabolic surface would be $z=u^2$, which is

$$z=(x-y)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

If you 'rotate the parabola you get a rotational paraboloid with the equation $u(x,y) = x^2+y^2$. Now you just need to plug in your values no matter what direction you want to go.

Comment: That's is not the same $x^2$ shape...

Comment: Yes it is, did you ever plot it?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2 - It's a different surface to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+%28y+-+x%29%5E2